# Updating database info from php, not saving

Tags: php, mysql

I have this code and it seems to be working. The values are updating, but when I reload the page the updated values are without any value. For example now I have set the title as "blablabla" and when I reload the page it's changing to "".

This is the code

```
<?php
$title = $_POST['title']; 
$meta = $_POST['meta'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$analytics = $_POST['analytics'];
$query = "UPDATE websettings SET title = '$title', meta = '$meta', email = '$email', analytics = '$analytics' WHERE id = '1'";
if(mysql_query($query)){ 
echo "success";
} 
else {
echo "fail";
} 
?>
```

Comment: try to echo the $query variable so you can see if you are passing the correct parameters. I guess that now $title, $meta and $email have a '' value. Also you are using a deprecated API (mysql_*) and you should move to mysqli_* or better PDO. Also your code is vulnerable to SQL_injections. Use prepared statements!

Comment: You know any better code for updating database info like mine? If yes can you give me it please?

Comment: It's not a matter of "better code". mysql_* functionalities are deprecated and will be removed in PHP version 7 that will be released soon. So your code will just stop working. SO is not a write code for me service. We can give you an hint based or put you on the right path to your goal. Anyway a simple search on SO itself will show you plenty of examples!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code applies `$_POST` variables to the database, but doesn't check if the client actually *posted* anything. Better to check if `$_POST` contains array items (if a form was posted), and check if each of those is set (if the user filled in the right fields), and validate the user input before saving (phone numbers, emails etc formatted correctly).

And as was pointed out in the comments you are vulnerable to SQL injection attack - one of the first things you should address.

Try turning on more PHP errors too - these would flag as unset variables for quicker fixing.

Comment: You know any better code for updating database info like mine? If yes can you give me it please?

Comment: Yes there is a [basic tutorial here](http://www.the-art-of-web.com/php/form-handler/) amongst many